# want to take value in a variable from output of EWS mail

Tags: php, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

i am taking the unread mail using EWS from Exchange server. below is the output.

```
stdClass Object ( [ResponseMessages] => stdClass Object 
            ( [FindItemResponseMessage] => stdClass Object 
    ( [ResponseCode] => NoError 
      [ResponseClass] => Success 
      [RootFolder] => stdClass Object 
    ( [Items] => stdClass Object 
    ( [Message] => stdClass Object 
    ( [ItemId] => stdClass Object 
    ( [Id] => AAMkADllYWVjYjE3LWMzNWItNDczYy05YzllLWEzMzM2YWUzNDY3NQBGAAAAAAA3RNrc1+NeRYdPKpmLrF8OBwDmmObTCfhpSqYuvnMiDlrXAAAAFjg7AADmmObTCfhpSqYuvnMiDlrXAAD0o9sFAAA= 
      [ChangeKey] => CQAAABYAAADmmObTCfhpSqYuvnMiDlrXAAD0o+gX 
    ) 
      [Subject] => CR-1167-Approved
      [Sensitivity] => Normal 
      [Size] => 2992 
      [DateTimeSent] => 2016-09-22T10:55:12Z 
      [DateTimeCreated] => 2016-09-22T10:55:13Z 
      [HasAttachments] => [IsAssociated] => [From] => stdClass Object 
      ( [Mailbox] => stdClass Object 
      ( [Name] => Basudev Kumar Sadhu (Assistant Manager, Technology)
        [MailboxType] => OneOff
       ) 
       ) 
         [IsRead] => 
       ) ) 
         [IndexedPagingOffset] => 1
       [IncludesLastItemInRange] => 1 
       [TotalItemsInView] => 1 
       ) ) ) )
```

Now i want to parse a value from this output. i want to capture Subject and Name from this output.

Below is my original code that i used to read the mail.

```
<?php
require_once ('../mail3/php-ews-master/ExchangeWebServices.php');
require_once ('../mail3/php-ews-master/EWS_Exception.php');
require_once ('../mail3/php-ews-master/EWSType.php');
require_once ('../mail3/php-ews-master/NTLMSoapClient.php');

 function __autoload($class_name)
 {
 // Start from the base path and determine the location from the class name,
 $base_path = '../mail3/php-ews-master';
 $include_file = $base_path . '/' . str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';

return (file_exists($include_file) ? require_once $include_file : false);
}

 //$message_id = ''; // Id of the email message
 $ews = new ExchangeWebServices("webmail.bkash.com", "cr.tool", "BanglaDesh!@34",ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2010);


$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();
$itemProperties = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$itemProperties->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES;
$itemProperties->BodyType = EWSType_BodyTypeResponseType::TEXT;
$request->ItemShape = $itemProperties;

$fieldType = new EWSType_PathToUnindexedFieldType();
$fieldType->FieldURI = 'message:IsRead';

$constant = new EWSType_FieldURIOrConstantType();
$constant->Constant = new EWSType_ConstantValueType();
$constant->Constant->Value = "0";

$IsEqTo = new EWSType_IsEqualToType();
$IsEqTo->FieldURIOrConstant = $constant;
$IsEqTo->Path = $fieldType;

$request->Restriction = new EWSType_RestrictionType();
$request->Restriction->IsEqualTo = new EWSType_IsEqualToType();
$request->Restriction->IsEqualTo->FieldURI = $fieldType;
$request->Restriction->IsEqualTo->FieldURIOrConstant = $constant;

$request->IndexedPageItemView = new EWSType_IndexedPageViewType();
$request->IndexedPageItemView->BasePoint = 'Beginning';
$request->IndexedPageItemView->Offset = 0;

$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;

$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;

$result = new EWSType_FindItemResponseMessageType();
$result = $ews->FindItem($request);

if ($result->ResponseMessages->FindItemResponseMessage->ResponseCode == 'NoError' && $result->ResponseMessages->FindItemResponseMessage->ResponseClass == 'Success'){

$count = $result->ResponseMessages->FindItemResponseMessage->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView;

if($count > 0) {
    echo $count . " email(s)";
    print_r($result);

} else {
    echo 'No email(s)';
}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using my version of that library [`garethp/php-ews`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews), which comes with many [`examples`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/tree/master/examples), including how to [get a list of mail items](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/examples/mail/listItems.php).

Working on that, your code would look roughly like

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword('server', 'username', 'password');
$mail = $api->getMailItems();

foreach ($mail as $mailItem) {
    $mailItem = $api->getItem($mail->getItemId());
    $subject = $mailItem->getSubject();
    $body = (string) $mailItem->getBody();
}
```

Comment: change this line it worked for me : `$mailItem = $api->getItem($mailItem->getItemId());`

Comment: Hey Gareth, in sendmail.php  how do we check if a mail is sent or not ?
`$return = $api->sendMail($message);`

Comment: If the server returns an error, an exception will be thrown, and you can catch that. If there's a normal response, you'll be bale to get the response as the return. My guess (though I haven't tested failing to send, I'm not sure when it would fail) is that a failure would result in an exception being thrown